# Elapsed time with only 2 digits

Tags: java, scala, bigdecimal

So in my scenario i am calculating times between 2 points and want to show this with only 2 decimal points.
This is what i have try:

```
import java.util.concurrent._
val startTmp = System.nanoTime
// Do my stuff...
val endTime = System.nanoTime
val elapsedTimeInSecondsTmp = BigDecimal(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(
          endTmp - startTmp, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) / 1000.0)
```

Comment: Just pass a `scale`  of 2 to the `BigDecimal`. "A BigDecimal consists of an arbitrary precision integer unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale. If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point." This is a Java question, BTW, as `BigDecimal` is a Java class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `setScale`

```
BigDecimal(19.1234).setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.DOWN)
=> res: scala.math.BigDecimal = 19.12
```